# Bad Request - Invalid URL

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, azure, asp.net-mvc-routing, azure-web-roles

I am having below mentioned issue when I am running Asp.Net MVC 2 project on windows Azure emulator (dev environment)

[image]

My web.config files is as below :

```
<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="4096" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" maxQueryStringLength = "4096" requestValidationMode="4.0" />
```

My URL with query string is as below :

> http://www.pawloyalty.com:82/booking/camp-canine-doggy-daycare-and-boarding/cgillette/key/camp-canine-doggy-daycare-and-boarding-cgillette-20130103154022/pets/bailey/service/full-day-care/dates/2013-1-3%2b2013-1-4%2b2013-1-7%2b2013-1-8%2b2013-1-9%2b2013-1-10%2b2013-1-11%2b2013-1-14%2b2013-1-15%2b2013-1-16%2b2013-1-17%2b2013-1-18%2b2013-1-21%2b2013-1-22%2b2013-1-23%2b2013-1-24%2b2013-1-25%2b2013-1-28%2b2013-1-29%2b2013-1-30%2b2013-1-31%2b2013-2-1%2b2013-2-4%2b2013-2-5%2b2013-2-6%2b2013-2-7%2b2013-2-8%2b2013-2-11%2b2013-2-12%2b2013-2-13%2b2013-2-14%2b2013-2-15%2b2013-2-18%2b2013-2-19%2b2013-2-20%2b2013-2-21%2b2013-2-22%2b2013-2-25%2b2013-2-26%2b2013-2-27%2b2013-2-28%2b2013-3-1%2b2013-3-4%2b2013-3-5%2b2013-3-6%2b2013-3-7%2b2013-3-8%2b2013-3-12%2b2013-3-13%2b2013-3-14%2b2013-3-15%2b2013-3-18%2b2013-3-19%2b2013-3-20%2b2013-3-21%2b2013-3-22%2b2013-3-25%2b2013-3-26%2b2013-3-27%2b2013-3-28%2b2013-3-29/rtimes/7.5%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19%2b6%2b19/rextras-bailey/-?step=dates

**Note :** above having `1490 characters`

My controller Action method's redirect is as below :

```
return RedirectToRoute("booking", new { action = "index", providerKey = providerKey, ownerKey = ownerKey, arguments = arguments, step = step });
```

**Note :** `arguments`  having above query string details

How to get rid of this error page ?

Comment: There are URL lengths limits, these vary between browsers. Your URL is abnormal of length

Comment: @RvdK I set it as "maxUrlLength="4096"" in web.config file but still having same issue ? Any idea ?

Comment: @Sampath there is url length set for per browser,IE only allows url of length 2083 characters

Comment: @Sampath this is not proper approach to pass data in URL,better use POST

Comment: @Sampath: this is serverside, the browser (on the client) does something different.

Comment: @Cris Actually I am sending this data to my next action method ("index") ? There is not any post data here.Only GET ?

Comment: you can avoid ugly URLs by sticking your values in TempData instead of the route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

keep your URL length under 2000 characters or use `POST` method rather than `GET`

Comment: Actually I am sending this data to my next action method ("index") ? There is not any post data here.Only GET ?

Comment: you can avoid ugly URLs by sticking your values in TempData instead of the route

Comment: Then Could you tell me why we set <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="4096"/> on web.config file ? Any Idea ?

Comment: @Sampath it is mostly used for web services for REST API calls which happens without using browsers,each browser has their own cap over url length and IE is smallest of them

Comment: Yes good point.But my whole URL having 1490 characters.So then it should work know ? Any idea ?

Comment: maybe one of the input parameter has some characters that violates the url specification,must be a maligned character present in url,refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid

Comment: No that is not the case here.B'cos my url maintained the above mentioned characters.My business Here is I am sending date kind of thing.when I select say 20 different dates it's working.When i am selecting around 50 dates it's not working.Any idea ?

Comment: try converting the DateTime to Ticks and pass that number around.

Comment: Thanks for your support.I have used TempData for send my data.Then problem vanished.